# Resolvido - Angularjs + Pagseguro - A lista não atualiza através do callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou tentando fazer uma listagem dos tipos de pagamentos disponíveis na api do pagseguro.

Para fazer isso eu uso uma função js do pagseguro chamada **PagSeguroDirectPayment.getPaymentMethods()**

O problema é que no callback dessa função, eu não consigo acessar as minhas variáveis do angular. Quando eu crio uma variável normal ele consegue acessar. Se eu coloco um botão para colocar os dados da variável normal na do angular ele funciona, mas eu queria ele carregasse no callback da função.

```
                var self = this;
                this.lista = [];

                PagSeguroDirectPayment.getPaymentMethods({
                    success: function(response) {                           
                        self.lista.push({"nome": "Cartão de Crédito", "img":"../static/img/cartao.png", "objpag": response.paymentMethods.CREDIT_CARD});
                        self.lista.push({"nome": "Débito Online", "img":"../static/img/debito.png", "objpag": response.paymentMethods.ONLINE_DEBIT});
                        self.lista.push({"nome": "Boleto", "img":"../static/img/barcode.png", "objpag": response.paymentMethods.BOLETO});
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                        //tratamento do erro
                    },
                    complete: function(response) {
                    }

                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para o binding funcionar em um callback eu tenho que força-lo. Para que isso seja possível existe a função **$scope.$apply()**.

Então no meu código teria que ficar assim:

```
            var self = this;
            this.lista = [];

            PagSeguroDirectPayment.getPaymentMethods({
                success: function(response) {                           
                    self.lista.push({"nome": "Cartão de Crédito", "img":"../static/img/cartao.png", "objpag": response.paymentMethods.CREDIT_CARD});
                    self.lista.push({"nome": "Débito Online", "img":"../static/img/debito.png", "objpag": response.paymentMethods.ONLINE_DEBIT});
                    self.lista.push({"nome": "Boleto", "img":"../static/img/barcode.png", "objpag": response.paymentMethods.BOLETO});
                    $scope.$apply();
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    //tratamento do erro
                },
                complete: function(response) {
                }

            });
```

quem quiser mais informações acesse o link: http://blog.fernandomantoan.com/angularjs-e-o-scope-apply/

to deixando a solução aqui mais para ajudar quem algum dia precisar, pq esse stackoverflow pt nunca me ajudou em nada.